# c++ error: mysterious conflicting declaration error

Tags: c++

I have carefully looked into my code but don't see why this error comes out.

The error message is the following:

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:12: error: conflicting declaration ‘traj dim’
main.cc:11: error: ‘dim’ has a previous declaration as ‘unsigned int dim’
```

and one can reproduce it with the following command

```
g++ -o a.out realvector.cc traj.cc main.cc
```

My main.cc is

```
#include "realvector.h"
#include "traj.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

  unsigned int dim=1000;
  traj TRAJ(dim);

  return 1;
}
```

traj is defined in traj.h as

```
#ifndef TRAJ
#define TRAJ


#include "realvector.h"


class traj{
  public:
    traj(unsigned int);
    ~traj();
    void next(double &);
  private:
    unsigned int it,nt;    // index, total array size
    double dt;             // step time
    RealVector r,v,a; 
};

#endif
```

the constructor is defined in traj.cc

```
#include "realvector.h"
#include "traj.h"

traj::traj(unsigned int dim) : nt(dim) {
  RealVector r(nt),v(nt),a(nt);
  it=0;
}


traj::~traj(){
  r.~RealVector();
}
```

Any idea why this error comes out? Also, is the way to define r,v,a correct? RealVector is a home-defined class with its constructors defined as the following

```
#include "realvector.h"
using namespace std;


RealVector::RealVector() {}

RealVector::RealVector(unsigned int n)
  : dim(n) {
  data = new double[dim];
  for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    data[i]=0;
}

RealVector::~RealVector(){
  delete[] data;
}
```

with realvector.h as

```
#ifndef REAL_VECTOR_H
#define REAL_VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>

class RealVector {
public:
  RealVector();
  RealVector(unsigned int n);
  ~RealVector();
  int dim; 
  double* data;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Sure you've included `traj.h` in main.cpp?

Comment: Not problem found http://ideone.com/PNPsY2

Comment: @bsmile: You initialize r, v, a with `traj::traj(unsigned int dim) : nt(dim), r(nt), v(nt), a(nt) {...`. But, before this will work you should probably make `traj::traj(unsigned int dim, unsigned int nt)`.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: thanks for all your comments, I have added all the missing pieces into my question, so the compilation should reproduce  the error message in my post.

Comment: @Saurav Sahu: thanks for your insight. I have compiled the minimum code you generated with the mysterious tool, where all code are included in a single file. The compilation is successful!? How come this be different from the way I compose the code?

Comment: @Saurav Sahu: thanks for the correct code you generated in ideone.com. I split it down to the way I write and found that it is the #define stuff used in traj.h that is causing the trouble. Anybody has any idea why this is the case, why the same #define stuff in realvector.h does not cause the trouble but help to get rid of some compilation error say mentioned by Laleh below?

Comment: it is not just "some define stuff". `#define TRAJ` is literally saying "TRAY is defined now and when it is found it will be replaced by empty". Then there is `traj TRAJ(dim);` which according to the rule becomes `traj (dim);` which the compiler doesn't like to much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `traj.h` you have

`#define TRAJ`

which defines `TRAJ` as an empty "string" and this leads to this replace by the preprocessor:

`traj TRAJ(dim);`

to

`traj (dim);`

which produces the error message.

I guess you should rename `TRAJ` in the include file to `TRAJ_H` and then it works.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. This credit should go to grek40, Revolver_ocelot and 6502 as well, to choose answer, I need to pick up Al Bundy's most clear one.

Comment: @bsmile if I felt like writing this as an answer I would have done it. It's just fine to credit the first answer that is addressing your issue.

Comment: @grek40: I agree with that, in that sense it is a bit unfair, but the answers are to help newbies, thus simpler and clearer answers are more helpful. It is after I figured out the mistake that I could finally get your points.

Comment: @bsmile Maybe I didn't make my point clear... you chose the answer that helped you, so you did the right thing. I didn't even write an answer, so there's no way I would complain just cause the credits go elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not complete... as a wild guess you also have a `TRAJ` macro that makes reading what the code really is impossible.

Comment: Probably an empty define for the include guard :D